# finding index[] of odd values in a list of integers?

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am trying to find the index value of some odd integers in a list. The program at its current stage only returns a new list containing only the odd integers.

[image of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkOjG.png)

This program returns the values [3, 5, 7]. How would i be able to retrieve the index of these odd values instead? For example, [0, 1, 3, 5] for the list shown above.

I have tried "position = dataItem1.index()". I understand that i would need to input an index value within the index brackets.

Comment: Post code as text, not as an image.

Comment: You can use a list comprehension which uses enumerate: `[i for i,n in enumerate(num_list) if n % 2 == 1]`

Comment: @interjay - i tried to copy and paste the code from Python v3 over to stack but it kept giving me an error about indentation was not correct for the code i pasted in. Have you got any tips?

Comment: @scarz.101 See [How do I format my code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/357835) for tips on how to post code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use also use `enumerate` : it returns the index of the element and the element (also, in python you can loop directly over the elements of a list, no need of while loops). I also encourage the use of `.append()` to add an element to a list, this is clearly more efficient than concatenate two lists as you do:

```
l = [0, 3, 2, 3, 4, 7, 6]

def get_odds_index(l):
    res = []
    for idx, val in enumerate(l):
        if val % 2 != 0:
            res.append(idx)
    return res

get_odds_index(l)
```

Comment: This WORKED! I knew that the append function adds elements or objects to the existing list but i don't quite understand how it works in this situation.

Comment: So there is a variable storing an empty set. Followed by a for loop, now I am not quite sure what the 'idx' truth-valued expression does. I have an idea that the val expression is to do with the values in the list L. Therefore if the val mod 2 is not equal to 0 we append the res (empty list) to 'idx'. Please explain what idx is doing in this example. Also thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding the element on that index in the odd list, just add index
Like this

```
def positionOfOdds(arr):
    odds = []
    length = len(arr)
    
    index = 0
    while index < length:
        data = arr[index]
        if data % 2 != 0:
            odds.append(index)
        index += 1
    return odds
```

Comment: which element? The [dataItem] element or index element?

Answer (score 0):

you already know the index, it is the loop variable

```py
def positionOfOdds(arr):
    odds = []
    length = len(arr)
    
    index = 0
    while index < length:
        data = arr[index]
        if data % 2 != 0:
            odds = odds + [index]
        index += 1
    return odds
```

Comment: my goal initially was to retrieve the index position of the list of odd numbers. So in my list example, wherever odd values were positioned it would return the position instead of the actual value.

Comment: something like this - PositionsOfOdds ([1,2,-3,4,-5]) returns [0,2,4]

Comment: what is the output you are getting when you run this code ?

Comment: It returns the new list containing all the odd values from the original list. Using @Muhammed program it works.

Comment: gives [0,2,4] for me

Comment: I will go over it again from scratch but i have managed to make it work. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You use an array called `odds` to store the odd numbers, to get the indexes you can create instead an array to store the indexes of the odd numbers, which I called `odds_idxs`. It should look something like this:

```py
num_list = [0, 3, 2, 3, 4, 7, 6]
def position_of_odds(num_list):
  odds_idxs = []
  length = len(num_list)
  index = 0
  while index < length:
    if num_list[index] % 2 != 0:
      odds_idxs = odds_idxs + [index]
    index = index + 1 
  return odds_idxs
```

Comment: I just figured out what you mean. Instead of creating a list that contains the odd numbers, i create the list odd_idx to contain the indexes of those odd numbers. However, i don't quite understand what "num_list[index]" does.